# Remove double quotes in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am getting in a list format `['Test']`

this i need to covert it like `('Test')`

I tried:

`test = '(' +test[0]+ ')'`

Output:

`'(Test)'`

And I tried:

```
test = "('"+"', '".join(test)+"')"
```

I got result in like:

`"('Test')"`

Remove double quotes in python. I need to get output like `('Test')`. But now am getting like this ``

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Show your code, please

Comment: kindly add your sample code

Comment: So if you use `print(test)` what output do you get?

Comment: These quotes are not part of the string itself. These state the start and end of the string. If a string contains single quotes, Python will use double quotes, such that the string can be represented more conveniently.

Comment: @iam supreeth, did any of the answers posted below help solve your problem? If so, you may mark the one that helped the most!

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

```
string = '''"('test')"'''

print(string.strip('"'))

>>> ('test')
```

Using `strip` you can remove any characters from a string.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is what you want:

```
str_list = ['Test1', 'Test2', 'Test3']
# desired output:  ('Test1', 'Test2', 'Test3')

# print(tuple(str_list))
print(str(tuple(str_list)).rstrip(',)') + ')')
```

OUTPUT:

```
('Test1', 'Test2', 'Test3')
```